# expression must have pointer to object type with structs

Tags: c

*** I find my mistake. c was already an int in this program . It was a big program(for me) and I had 20 variables and got confused. thank you. by the way, this option for copying a struct worked for me in the end.**

I am trying to copy a structure, and it tells me that i need to put a pointer I think.
I like to mention that I didnt use pointers in all my program.

I've done a code of a game. it's a 500 hundred code and ran smoothly, until I tried to copy a structure.
I equaled it with a lot of people that did similar to me, and they don't have my problem. I also searched in all of the web.
It writed to me two types of errors that I will add below.
thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct player {
    char name[ARR_SIZE]; // player's name, up to 20 chars
    int age; // player's age, 0 - 120
    int defense; // defense power, 1 - 100
    int attack; // attack power, 1 - 100
}player;

typedef struct team {
    char name[ARR_SIZE]; // team's name
    int numberOfPlayers; // number of players in the team, up to MAX_PLAYERS
    player teamPlayers[MAX_PLAYERS]; // array of the team players
    int points; // the team points in the league
    int wins; // number of wins
    int draws; // number of draws
    int losses; // number of losses
}team;

team b[MAX_TEAMS_NUMBER];
team c[MAX_TEAMS_NUMBER]; (1)

** the part of the code itself**
int main ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_teams; i++)
        {
            c[i] = b[i]; (2)
        }
}
```

I denoted numbers near the problematic lines
(1)'c': 'team[10]' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
(2) Expression must have a pointer to object type

Comment: Can you move `team b[MAX_TEAMS_NUMBER];
team c[MAX_TEAMS_NUMBER];` after you have defined the new type `team` using `typedef`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Comment: I see code (`for(int i....)`), but it is not in any function!  You cannot have free-floating code.  It must be inside a function.

Comment: hi iam really sorry for not mention this, but all the code(of course just the loop and the declarations) is inside the main(int), and the two lines of declaration are under the two structures, in my original code. I will edit the question. thank you!

Comment: I found my mistake and wrote it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

In C, the code order is very important. Here, you first try to create an array of "teams", then you tell the compiler what a "team" is. As it will read your code line by line, it doesn't know what a team is when reading your 2 first lines.

You must move the 2 first lines after your structures.

Keep in mind this problem can also occur with functions : if you use a function BEFORE its declaration, the compiler will detect an error. (declaration isn't implementation, you can implement a function at the bottom of your code but you need to declare it using a prototype.)

Comment: Im really sorry, in the original code it is not like that, it is below the structures. thank you for the comment, I will edit the question.

Comment: I found my mistake and wrote it in the question.